# Finding a Borel measurable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measurable-functions

Let $f :[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. Can we find a Borel measurable function $ g :(0,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ such that $g(x)\in (0,x)$ and $f(x)=f(0)+f'(g(x))x$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$?

Comment: $f(x)=x$ is a counterexample since $f'(g(x))=1$ for any $g$

Comment: @user363464 I think you've misread the question - $f(x) = x$ is an example. Let $g(x) = 0$ for all $x$; then $f(0) + f'(g(x))x = f(0) + f'(0)x = 0 + x = x = f(x)$.

Comment: @Reese that makes more sense, i didn't read the stop "." as multiplication

Comment: @user363464 I just removed the dot.

Comment: @Reese Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a set-valued function $G:(0,\infty)\to \mathcal P[0,\infty)$ by

$$G(x)=\operatorname{argmax}\limits_{t\in[0,x]} \left|f(t)-f(0)-t\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\right|.$$

The intuition is that $t\in G(x)$ means that $t$ is one of the solutions coming from the usual proof of the mean value theorem, though instead of picking an extreme point in Rolle's theorem we select all of them at this stage. It may also include $0$ and $x$ as a convenience.

Considered as a set, $G$ is relatively closed in $(0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$ - if $t_n\in G(x_n)$ and $(t_n,x_n)\to (t,x)$ then $t\in G(x).$ By the proof of Rolle's theorem we know that for each $x$ there is some $0<t<x$ with $t\in G(x).$ The only problem is how to select a unique $t$ for each $x.$ We can get an at-most-two-valued function by defining
$$G'(x)=\operatorname{argmin}_{t\in G(x)}|t-x/2|.$$
One way to see this is Borel is to observe that $x\mapsto \min_{t\in G(x)}|t-x/2|$ is a lower semicontinuous function. Finally we can define the single-valued function
$$g(x)=G'(x)\setminus \{x-t\mid t\in G'(x), t>x/2\}.$$
to disambiguate the cases where $F'(x)=\{t, x-t\}.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! now I am trying to digest it and will accept it as an answer.